# Show quiz result on the same page in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

[Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) allows to create questionnaire and make it like a quiz in order to get score to correct answers.

I created a quiz in Google Forms but after submitting answers to all questions it shows a button "View score", after clicking on it shows quiz result on a new page. How to make it open quiz scores on the same page? Any guess?

Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdKXs2SpRV5xCEG3iL2lKz6gKV1-qsVzRfCvTFb5oH1PBJ2Gg/viewform?usp=sf_link) to my sample quiz.

[image]

Comment: I am embedding this form inside iframe, that's why your suggestion doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to comment on your question or message you but I don't have enough reputation to do that.  The questionnaire you created is set as a "quiz" where it has default settings by Google and you can't change it nor redirect your page on form submit.  However Google has a way for you to customize or add features to your form and that is using google app script.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/