# How to Redirect to another Website upon Google Form Submission?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form which is backed by a Google Apps Script with an onFormSubmit function, which fires when the Form is submitted. The next thing I want to do is, after the Form data processing is done by the Apps Script, the Script should redirect the user to another website. I would appreciate your help in figuring out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script can't redirect to another website because it only acts on the back-end  not on the front-end.

Related

This site

- [Show quiz result on the same page in Google Forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123410/88163)

Stack Overflow

- [Old Google Form redirect after submission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6077054/1595451) (This doesn't work with the current version of Google Forms)
- [Google Form App Script Automatic URL Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29421751/1595451)